# Titanium full screen image splash screen

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've started a new project and replaced all png files in the newly created project with my own. But instead of a full size image for the splash screen I got a centered image which is my icon.

I added the `LaunchLogo` files but it's still just centered. <strike>I even tried disabling storyboard:</strike>

```
<enable-launch-screen-storyboard>false</enable-launch-screen-storyboard>
```

It did not work. How can I setup a fulll screen splash like in old Titanium versions?

**Edit:**

After cleaning the project setting `enable-launch-screen-storyboard` to `false` worked.

So I have 2 options:

1. Disable storyboard and use "old" titanium way.
2. Create a custom storyboard.

So my current question is why use a storyboard over "legacy" splash screen at all? are there any advantages? performance?

Comment: advantages, no need for images full-size, just a single one cross all devices

Comment: @RenePot thats assuming that I have a centralized image on solid background, right? What if I need a full screen image for splash?

Comment: In that case there indeed is no point for a storyboard unless you make one yourself, but in that case might as well use images. Storyboards can do more than just display an image, so there is an advantage if you want to use that

Comment: @RenePot No point at creating a Storyboard with only one big image that covers all and fits the screen? What else can Storyboard offer?

Comment: For storyboards you could also add default UI elements... so loading spinner, or some text. There are some options

Comment: @RenePot Thanks. Can storyboard splash screen contain logic? If for example I want to show different splash screen depending on a value stored in the database?

Comment: I heavily doubt it

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the sizes of the Splashscreens are wrong. Try creating a new project and copy over the Splashscreens or check the sizes at:

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Icons+and+Splash+Screens#IconsandSplashScreens-iOSgraphicassetrequirementsandoptions

Comment: All sizes are correct. Storyboard just takes an image and centers it.

Comment: And phone/ipad is switched on in tiapp.xml too?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my question - see if that information is relevant